# Changes are not saved on shutdown [ Linux / Jetson Nano ]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, persistence

Whenever I restart my Jetson Nano (Ubuntu 18.04.06), **all changes I made are reset**. The Jetson used to work fine and no major settings have been changed. There are also previous changes on the Jetson Nano that don't disappear when restarted.
**To clarify: Changes ANYWHERE on the machine are not saved after restart/shutdown and I'm not using a live USB**

I have tried accessing the computer directly with keyboard/mouse as well as through ssh and ensured that the ssh doesn't put you into guest mode. I also checked the disk space and there seems to be plenty.

Please let me know if you have any ideas as I am currently stuck! Anything helps!

Progress update:
Completely stuck for weeks. I would appreciate if someone could offer any advice as I don't have the rep for a bounty.

Comment: Can you give an example of change? If you create a file in your home directory, does the file disappear after reboot? Are you using a normal installation or using a live usb?

Comment: Normal installation and it's any file change whether in home or a system settings file

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recently came back to the jetson nano, and found out that i was having the same problems that you´re describing, furthermore i found out that the contents of files that were created or modified before shutdown were deleted. I´m guessing  that the problem has to do with cache.
For now what seems to be working is to do a sync before shutdown. this command writes everything you have in cache to persistent storage.

```
$> touch t.txt
$> echo "this is a test" >> t.txt
$> cat t.txt
$> sync
$> shutdown
```

after reboot you should be able to see the changes made to the file.

Hopefully this helps.